# Why is the $ \lim_{x\to\infty} ((-0.5)^x + 0.5)^x= 0$

Tags: limits

Why is,
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} ((-0.5)^x + 0.5)^x= 0 \space?$$

I understand that it behaves like $$\lim_{x\to\infty} ((-0.5)^x)^x=\lim_{x\to\infty} (-0.5)^{x^2},$$ but still, why is the limit 0? How can it be shown?

Additionally, how does the result change if x is integer (from 2 to infinity)?

Comment: What is $(-0,5)^x$ for $x>0$ ?? For example: what is $\sqrt{-0,5}$ ???

Comment: Isn't it the imaginary root? Also, in the problem I'm concerned with, x is integer (from 2 to infinity).

Comment: @Val9265: from your post, $x$ is a real number (and as a secondary question you ask for integer $x$). What is $(-0.5)^\pi$ ?

Comment: "I understand that it behaves like...": how can you say that ? (by the way it is false)

Comment: @Yves Daoust I'm not sure what's the significance of $(-0.5)^{\pi}$? All I know is that evaluates to some complex number.

Comment: @Val9265: I am not so sure.

Comment: For real $x$, the limit does not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is elementary that the sequence $|r^n|$ goes decreasing and tends to zero for $|r|<1$. (Indeed $|r^{n+1}|=|r^n|\,|r|<|r^n|$ and the geometric series converges to $1/(1-r)$.)

Then for $n>2$,

$$0.25\le(-0.5)^n+0.5\le0.75$$ so that we can squeeze
$$0\le((-0.5)^n+0.5)^n\le0.75^n.$$